# How to automatically load a new VID&PID to module usb_serial

Tags: kernel-modules, udev, power-management, lte, huawei

I have a 4G module that requires me to run

```
echo '03f0 581d' > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/generic/new_id
```

after every startup/resume to make the modem visible. How should I make this automatic?

- Add the VID&PID to usb-serial sources and recompile
- Create script that run on startup/resume that adds them dynamically
- Some sort of udev rule?

What would be the best approach. I think the `udev` approach sounds the most reasonable. I assume that would work over suspend/resume too?

The modem is a HP lt4112 LTE/HSPA+ Gobi 4G Modem (Huawei ME906E).

Bonus question: Why does the command need to be re-run after a suspend/resume cycle. Does the kernel module get unloaded or somehow reset when the laptop gets suspended to RAM?

Comment: @don_crissti I've thought the primary function of usb_modeswitch was to send some kind of payloads to the device to for example switch from storage mode to serial mode. I guess it might handle attaching right modules as well

Comment: @don_crissti Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your device's vendor and product IDs are as configured above, ie `03f0` and `581d` respectively, you can create a [udev](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev) rule that will automatically initialize the device and bind it to [libqmi](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/libqmi/), as shown below:

`file /etc/udev/rules.d/98-modem-rules.rules`

Create the file using your favorite text editor (and appropriate permissions, `sudo` is required) with the content:

```bsh
ACTION!="add|change", GOTO="mbim_to_qmi_rules_end"
SUBSYSTEM!="usb|drivers", GOTO="mbim_to_qmi_rules_end"

# load qmi_wwan module
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", \
ATTR{idVendor}=="03f0", ATTR{idProduct}=="581d", \
RUN+="/sbin/modprobe -b qmi_wwan"

# Initialize the LTE lt112 module to operational status:
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", \
ATTR{idVendor}=="03f0", ATTR{idProduct}=="581d", \
ATTR{bConfigurationValue}="3"

# add the new id in the qmi_wwan driver
SUBSYSTEM=="drivers", \
ENV{DEVPATH}=="/bus/usb/drivers/qmi_wwan", \
ATTR{new_id}="03f0 581d"

# load qcserial module
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", \
ATTR{idVendor}=="03f0", ATTR{idProduct}=="581d", \
RUN+="/sbin/modprobe -b qcserial"

# add the new id in the qcserial driver
SUBSYSTEM=="drivers", \
ENV{DEVPATH}=="/bus/usb-serial/drivers/qcserial", \
ATTR{new_id}="03f0 581d"
LABEL="mbim_to_qmi_rules_end"
```

On your machine, you'll also need to install the appropriate packages:

Assuming Ubuntu (as no distribution information was given), run:

`sudo apt install libqmi libqmi-utils`

When done, activate the new udev rule:

```bsh
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
sudo udevadm trigger
```

You may also find [modem-manager](https://linuxonly.ru/page/modem-manager-gui), a GUI front-end to see modem stats, such as network signal strength, etc, to be of use.

It can be installed via:

`sudo apt install modem-manager-gui`

A cold start will be required after inserting a SIM card.

**Update:**

An alternative to this would be to install the package `usb-modeswitch-data` (which will also pull in [usb-modeswitch](https://linux.die.net/man/1/usb_modeswitch) as a dependency).

The package contains udev rules that allow usb-modeswitch to initialize the device correctly, with multiple entries for multiple devices. See the changelog(s) on the same [here](https://debian.pkgs.org/9/debian-main-i386/usb-modeswitch-data_20170120-1_all.deb.html).

The udev rules in the package are stored in a file called `40-usb_modeswitch.rules`. For your particular hardware, its' on line 32-33:

```bsh
# HP hs4112
ATTR{idVendor}=="03f0", ATTR{idProduct}=="581d", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '/%k'"
```

After installing `usb-modeswitch` and `usb-modeswitch-data`, you'll need to reboot, even after reloading udev rules before the SIM card is recognized.

Comment: usb-modeswitch seems like the easiest option now. Support for the 4112 was added a year after I asked the question so it was not an option at the time.